# My Lenovo tablet screen is stuck on "Test Report" and won't turn off or anything else

Tags: lenovo-laptop

For the 1st time today, I charged my Lenovo tablet through my Toshiba laptop. It displayed a series of different things such as:

- status:start inquiring...,
- "Factory Mode" showing "Manuel test", Item test, test report, debug test, Clear eMMC, Version, Reboot.

Then it showed a date and time on the screen 2008/12/31 23:59:53. Then the screen switched to "GPS Initializing"...

Then it showed GPS TIFF (a) : O (I couldn't clearly read it, but I think that's what it displayed). From there it went to "GPS" counting to 60 or more seconds and finally the screen froze at 'TEST REPORT'.

I'm not able to do anything with it now, not even turn it off! Could this have happened because I decided to charge it through my laptop, in which I have never done before now? Can someone PLEASE help me to restore my Lenovo tablet?

Comment: Sounds like it is time for Lenovo support.